# Error while trying to pass a text file as argument

Tags: java

so I am learning how to pass files as argument in java. I am trying to implement a scheduling algorithm in java but my issue is the console shows the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Since I am totally new to this, I am not sure where I am doing wrong. I can get the program to scan the input text file normally using an object from the scanner class but when I try and pass it as an argument, I get the above error. How do I fix this error? The program below is not the full program but big enough to compile and show the error I am getting. I am using an online IDE atm and I have a 'file.txt' that contains integer values I want. I believe the error's got something to do with the args statement. Can anyone help me fix this please?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int i=0,j=0;
        if(args.length<1)
        {
          System.out.println("ERRRRRRRORRRRRR!");
        }
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        
            int n= scan.nextInt();
            int process_id[] = new int[n];
            int burst_time[] = new int[n];
            int arrival_time[] = new int[n];
            n=0;
            while(n<3){
                process_id[i]= scan.nextInt();
                burst_time[i]= scan.nextInt();
                arrival_time[i]= scan.nextInt();
                n++;
                i++;                  
            }
            }
            }
```

Comment: give us the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to 'return' out of main when args.length<1.
Your code detects the empty args but do nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

either you need to put your logic in else part or you need to stop program in if condition by return or System.exit(0);